# Regular Expression convert to MYSQL format

Tags: sql, mysql, regex

I have a Regular Expression `.*\/(\d+)(?![^(]*\))` that it works in other program e.g., C#. And I want to use it in MYSQL, and it return error

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(myStr, '.*\/(\d+)(?![^(]*\))'), c.* FROM mytable c;
/* SQL Error (1139): Regex error 'unmatched closing parenthesis at offset 16' */
```

The Regular Expression actually will return result like below. It get the number next to last "/" that not inside brackets

```
e.g.,
string: "/13/A01(VE)(S)", expected result: "13"
string: "(2)/1(D/3G)", expected result: "1"
string: "/S03(RED/09)/1/(TN)", expected result: "1"
string: "/2(V)/8", expected result: "8"
string: "/BR03(JTF07)(CE)(W)/9", expected result: "9"
string: "(NT)/2(U/V)(J)", expected result: "2"
```

Comment: Can there be nested parens, such as"(x(y)z)"?  This might make the skipping over parens complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your regex is that you have `\d` and `\)` which appear in the regex as `d` and `)` (due to string parsing prior to the regex engine) the latter then causes an "unmatched closing parenthesis" error at the next `)`. You need to escape the `\` to ensure you get `\d` and `\)` into the regex i.e.:

```
'/(\\d+)(?![^(]*\\))'
```

Note the `.*` at the beginning of the regex is not necessary as you are not interested in those characters anyway.

Assuming you are using MySQL > 8.0.4, when the switch was made to the ICU engine, this will work fine, although it will give you a string ending with the last digits following a `/` but not inside brackets. You then just need to extract those digits, which you can do with another regex:

```
\\d+$
```

In SQL:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(myStr, '/(\\d+)(?![^(]*\\))'), '\\d+$') FROM myTable;
```

Demo on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ojz93dEF)

Comment: The leading `.*` is unnecessary.

Comment: @RickJames good point, I blindly copied that from OPs code. I've updated the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that works:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(myStr, '\\([^)]*\\)', ''), '.*/([[:digit:]]+).*', '$1') AS `result`
FROM myTable;
```

Output given your example strings, tested on MySQL 8.3.0:

```
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| 13     |
| 1      |
| 1      |
| 8      |
| 9      |
| 2      |
+--------+
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/s7oJvcj7

Comment: Lookaheads are supported as of the change to ICU in 8.0.4. OPs main problem is that they didn't escape the \ in their regex. See my answer and demo

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the clarification. I've edited my answer. It's still true that the solution I posted works, but I removed my comment about lookaheads.

Comment: No problem, I think this is a good answer which will also work prior to 8.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Instead of (wrong) escaping open parentheses, I put it inside a bracket as
`'.*\/(\d+)(?![^(]*[)])'` .

Or escape it by double backslash as follows:
`'.*\/(\d+)(?![^(]*\\))'`

Comment: Still same error `/* SQL Error (1139): Regex error 'unmatched closing parenthesis at offset 16' */`

Comment: Now using `'.*\/(\d+)(?![^(]*[)])'` or `'.*\/(\d+)(?![^(]*\\))'` it did not return error, but the result that returned not the same as the original regular expression. The example that provided all return empty string instead of the expected result.

Comment: Can you explain which pattern are you looking for?

Comment: Just the example I provided in the question. It will get the number next to last "/" that not inside brackets. You can see to some of the expected result in the question.

Comment: SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(myStr, '.*\/(\\d+)(?![^(]*\\))'), '\\d+$') s,  c.* FROM   mytable c